# How to submit values in form and save them on another page [PHP]?

Tags: php, forms, input

so I have 2 pages . On the first page I have a form , where I need to input values and the other page receives those values and **saves** them. Then I go back to page 1 , input new values and those new values get saved again on page 2 , right next to the previous values. Basically like a shopping list. The problem is that i'm really new to PHP and I can't really find solution how to save these forms next to each other. Massive thanks to anyone who replies.

Page 1 :

```
<fieldset style="width:fit-content; margin:170px; auto  10px; font-size: 30px; justify-content:center;">
  <form action="./site2.php" method="post" >
  <legend>Product add</legend>
  <label>SKU:<br />
  <input type="text" name="SKU" pattern="[0-9.]+" required id="SKU" /></label><br />
  <label>Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="name" required id="name" /> </label><br>
  <label>Price($):<br />
  <input  required id="price" pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text" name="price" ></label><br />
  
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"  >
 <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
```

Page 2 :

```
<form action="site1.php" method="get">
```

```
<?php

session_start();
$data=array();

if(!isset($_SESSION['data'])){
 $_SESSION['data'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
  $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST['SKU']; 
  $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST['name']; 
  $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST['price']; 
}

foreach($_SESSION['data'] as $d){

}
?>
```

```
<form id="form-list" > 
<fieldset style="width: fit-content; margin:130px; auto  10px; font-size: 20px; justify-content:center; " > 

   
     SKU: <?php echo $d; ?><br>
    
    Product name: <?php echo $d; ?><br>

     Price($): <?php echo $d; ?><br>
    
    <input type="checkbox" value="asd" id="test" name="test" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have read a little, and are trying to build something based on that reading. Good start. but I think you need to take a further dive into the litterature.

## Concepts

1. PHP is a server side language. everything inside the `<?php` and  `?>` tags is executed on the server, and not on the client.
2. HTML is a (most often) client side markup (display) language, and is executed on the client (in the browser)
3. When you have both php and html in a php file (and it is sent with the proper headers) the php code is executed, and any `echo` or `print` or `<?="hello world"?>` is converted to text on your html page, and the resulting file is executed by the client's browser
4. Anything in your `$_SESSION` is available to your PHP sections as they are executed, providing the session (set by the cookie or a path parameter) is the same

## What your code is doing

### Page 1 (site1.php)

- Displays a html form (could in reality be just a .html file instead, if you have no other php in the file)

### Page 2 (site2.php)

- starts a `<form>` element which would submit the form to site1.php
- parses the submitted form data and saves it in a session variable
- parses an empty `foreach` loop
- displays some html elements with an apparently unset php variable `$d`
- creates a checkbox
- closes the `<form>` without a sumbit button, which means you never get back to site1.php

## Solution 1: Do everything in a single php file

```php
<!-- input part -->
<html>
<body>
<fieldset style="width:fit-content; margin:170px; auto  10px; font-size: 30px; justify-content:center;">
  <form action="" method="post" >
  <legend>Product add</legend>
  <label>SKU:<br />
  <input type="text" name="SKU" pattern="[0-9.]+" required id="SKU" /></label><br />
  <label>Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="name" required id="name" /> </label><br>
  <label>Price($):<br />
  <input  required id="price" pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text" name="price" ></label><br />
  
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"  >
 <input type="reset" value="Cancel">

 <!-- form input handling -->

<?php

session_start();
$data=array();

if(!isset($_SESSION['data'])){
 $_SESSION['data'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
  $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST['SKU']; 
  $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST['name']; 
  $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST['price']; 
}

foreach($_SESSION['data'] as $d){
 echo "SKU: ".$d['SKU']."<br>".
      "Product name: ".$d['name']."<br>".
      "Price($): ".$d['price']."<br>";
}
?>
<!-- some link to save.php where you push $_SESSION['data'] to your persistent databse (MySQL/PostgresQL/whatever)-->
</body>
```

## Solution 2 (advanced):

- keep your setup with site1.php and site2.php, but keep site2.php as pure php without html, and return the data as json or xml
- use ajax (javascript) to submit the form to site2.php and parse the return data to a visible format
- have a third file (e.g. save.php) where you do the saving to a dbms

## Solution 3: keep your code and fix the issues

- put your display code inside the `foreach` (see my code)
- remove the `<form>` from site2.php and simply add a `<a href="site1.php">add more items</a>` link at the bottom to go back to the input page

Answer (score -1):

So a couple of things here, if you want to **save** your values on another page, you're going to need some sort of intermediary to **save** your values. This is where databases / caches shine.

Just use your preferred storage utility, and call it in your shopping cart with a SELECT / foreach loop.